# Does this audit make sense?

Tags: discussion, review

In a first post rewiew I got the question:

**What kind of power port is this**

I added this comment: `This question with exactly this picutres has been asked before, look here: ...`

and got this result:

[image]

And really, I wanted to flag it as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to agree that this wasn't an appropriate review audit.

It's an old post that probably would get closed or downvoted if posted today.

Unfortunately, review audit selection is random and managed by SE employees who strongly prefer to use as much automation as possible to reduce "overhead" and human workload. Sadly, there are so many places where human intervention is required and we cannot totally cut out the human factor in such subjective things as reviews...

I have a feeling it would take a huge outcry from multiple full ♦moderators before they'll change it. See: [Bring a "human factor" into review audit composition/selection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection)

Comment: Maybe it would already be an improvement not to judge the fact, that somebody is leaving a comment. (At least not when a "wanted" post is used for an audit.)

Comment: There is a solution.  If it's that poor of a question the community can delete it.  If it would be closed, just because it has up votes does not make it valid