# Stop, Look & Listen… meh

Tags: discussion, review-audits

STOP! Look and Listen.
This was an audit, designed to …
irritate & infuriate, even if I *get it right*

It was a Link-only answer & I flagged it as such.

When will this infuriating 'test' cease?

The review audit in question is https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/331912.

Comment: See also: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9008/does-this-audit-make-sense/9009#9009

Comment: It happens to all of us - that said, the *comments* have some valuble info rounding off the question, and its a highly upvoted answer, which is probably why it was picked as a review audit.

Comment: Meh... just get over it. It is really not worth the frustration. (see also: http://meta.superuser.com/q/8198/281154s)

Answer (score 2):

It happens from time to time… and it's hard to tune this review system to deal with such cases (e.g. a highly upvoted answer that would've otherwise been auto-flagged as low quality).

Instead of flagging it, I would have probably tried to edit some more relevant information into the post. But as you can see there's not a lot to add there either, because the official documentation gives quite a good explanation.

I agree that *any* action taken on a post that is deemed "fine" by the system should not cause an audit failure. But I'm pretty sure that this has already been requested on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Just think of it that way: you did the right thing in any case if you're not just blindly clicking "looks fine". One audit failure will not have any impact on your account's standing.

Comment: Thank you slhck, & apologies for the <rant>. I just felt I was trying to do 'the right thing' & some machine slapped my wrists.

Comment: Also said - I didn't check the links to see whether they were 'good' answers, as I've learned that on SE giving a 'bad or incorrect' answer is not in itself reason to flag. i would only really check links carefully in review if there was a smell of spam or similar 'PUP' to the post. I always hover the link to check it goes where it appears to.